# TypeORM and NestJS: Creating database tables at the beginning of an e2e test

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to have database tables created at the beginning of each test or test run, so that either 1) all migrations are run against the test database, or 2) a single migration sets up all the tables (faster). [This would be on a similar fashion as Django does it](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.5.x/topics/testing/overview.html#the-test-database).

Is there a way to automate this easily with TypeORM, so that I do not need manually maintain a copy of a test database? Naturally, at the end of a test the opposite, tear down and table purge needs to happen.

Currently, my test fails:

```
● User › GET /users › should return an array of users

    QueryFailedError: relation "user" does not exist

      at new QueryFailedError (../src/error/QueryFailedError.ts:9:9)
      at Query.callback (../src/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.ts:178:30)
      at Query.Object.<anonymous>.Query.handleError (../node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:145:17)
      at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (../node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:214:17)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:134:12)
```

Apparently... does not fail if I manually run migrations against `e2e_test` database.

My test code:

```js
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as supertest from 'supertest';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { User } from '../src/user/user.entity';
import { UserModule } from '../src/user/user.module';

describe('User', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let repository: Repository<User>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        UserModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 54320,
          username: 'local_dev',
          password: 'local_dev',
          database: 'e2e_test',
          entities: ['./**/*.entity.ts'],
          synchronize: false,
        }),
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();
    repository = module.get('UserRepository');
    await app.init();
  });

  afterEach(async () => {
    await repository.query(`DELETE FROM users;`);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  describe('GET /users', () => {
    it('should return an array of users', async () => {
      await repository.save([{ displayName: 'test-name-0' }, { displayName: 'test-name-1' }]);

      const { body } = await supertest
        .agent(app.getHttpServer())
        .get('/users')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);
      expect(body).toEqual([
        { id: expect.any(Number), name: 'test-name-0' },
        { id: expect.any(Number), name: 'test-name-1' },
      ]);
    });
  });

});
```

[Example loosely based on this tutorial by Paul Salmon](https://medium.com/@salmon.3e/integration-testing-with-nestjs-and-typeorm-2ac3f77e7628).

Comment: Hello!

To get the connection from your test module, you can do:

    const connection = module.get(Connection);

I can't try it right now, but you can try to set the synchronize parameter to true in the TypeOrmModule.forRoot and only import the entity you want to create in the entities parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like one can fish out `connection` of TypeORM and then call its `synchronise` method.

If someone 1) knows a better way to obtain the connection 2) knows if it is a right time to call `synchronise` please drop a comment.

[This issue was discussed on Github](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/409#issuecomment-391508916)

```js
describe('User', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let repository: Repository<User>;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        UserModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 54320,
          username: 'local_dev',
          password: 'local_dev',
          database: 'e2e_test',
          entities: ['./**/*.entity.ts'],
          synchronize: false,
        }),
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();

    repository = module.get('UserRepository');
    const connection = repository.manager.connection;
    // dropBeforeSync: If set to true then it drops the database with all its tables and data 
    await connection.synchronize(true); 

    await app.init();
  });
```